# wp7 - is it possible to have a user control loaded between pages?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to solve some problems with AdMob control in my game, and the control takes some time to load (it hijacks UI thread for up to 1 second). Is it possible to load the control once, then store it somewhere and attach it to the visual tree for the subsequent pages?

Or this cannot be done and I do have to find some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to save the states of that control on that page.

[Please refer this MSDN Documentation for states of windows phone 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967547%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

I hope you can better idea from this

UPDATE ====

```
 Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(delegate()
            {
               // Load Your Control Here
            }));
```

It will not freeze your UI

Comment: No, the problem is, that Google AdMob control takes some time to load (and freezes the entire page), so I'd like to load it somewhere and then insert it into target page. Control state wouldn't help as it would freeze the page once again.

Comment: According to the docs - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx - Dispatcher works on the UI thread, so it shouldn't make any difference, but I'll try

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the control on a page in runtime with:

```
this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add( control )
```

If you statically define your control, you can then remove it from the current page on the OnNavigatingFrom event and after that load it on the next page or something similar to prevent crashing from multiple parents.